# SUM() in SAS from same table where statement

Tags: sas

trying to figure out how I can make the below happen in SAS:
so on the compare column I would like to add (both amount to both item 1 and 2 separately)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do.

```
data have;
input state $ compare $ comp_cnt;
datalines;
NY Both 4000
NY Item1 3500
NY Item2 2000
KY Both 5000
KY Item1 3000
KY Item2 4000
;

   proc SQL;
   select a.state, 
          a.compare,
          a.comp_cnt +b.comp_cnt as comp_cnt
   from 
   (select * from have
    where compare ne 'Both')a
    left join
    (select * from have
     where compare ='Both')b
     on a.state=b.state;
     quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Thxs Kiran, just wanted to let you know that worked perfectly... don't know why I didn't thk about that ! lol